# immutables: should we use the Interface or ImmutableValueObject

Tags: java, immutables-library

The question is about using the [immutables](http://immutables.github.io/) java library.

In their documentation they seem to use the `ImmutableValueObject` only to construct the instance and then in the code they use the `ValueObject` (interface or abstract base class) like this:

```
ValueObject valueObject =
    ImmutableValueObject.builder()
        .name("My value")
        .addCounts(1)
        .addCounts(2)
        .build();
```

Wouldn't it be better to always just use the `ImmutableValueObject`?

e.g.:

```
ImmutableValueObject valueObject =
    ImmutableValueObject.builder()
        .name("My value")
        .addCounts(1)
        .addCounts(2)
        .build();
```

Especially for method parameters, etc. the `ValueObject` does not guarantee immutability (e.g. someone could just subclass the `ValueObject` and pass a mutable instance).

Often, I want to use an interface, because I can simply use a different implementation in my tests. But in the case of an immutable object (which is just a data-object), I don't need this: in the test I just prepare my object the way it should be.

Are there any other reasons, I am missing?

Comment: also asked this directly on their github page: https://github.com/immutables/immutables/issues/599

Comment: The difference doesn't appear that big to me. An `ImmutableValueObject` instance contains a number of `with*`-methods that can be used to create slightly modified copies, but not much else as far as I can see. It just seems cleaner to me to use the `ValueObject` references everywhere, and only invoke the Immutables framework when a new instance must be created.